# Google Play Timed Publishing - release and alpha/beta track at the same time

Tags: google-play, publishing, timed

This is the scenario:

1. I turned on timed publishing.
2. I created and submitted a release on a production track (Initial 1.0 release).
3. "Go live" button became blue after some time.
4. I made numerous fixes and created a new release on the alpha track and I want my testers to look at it before I release the build on the production track. Button "Go live" became grey.
5. "Go live" button is blue again. Now here is my question:

What happens when I click on the "Go live" button? Will the app be released on both tracks? Will I be able to pick? I'm scared to click on it because I don't want to release my app to production to production yet

Also when the "Go live" button is blue does that mean that the app is approved or is it just that the build was processed and there is an additional review after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had to figure this out on my own:

- When you hit "Go live" in this scenario BOTH VERSIONS (alpha/beta and production) ARE RELEASED.
- Also when the "Go live" button is blue: yes, that does mean that the app is approved and will be released immediately.

So if you find yourself in this scenario as well you are out of luck and you have to release both versions. If you unpublish your app BOTH alpha/beta and production will be unpublished. They can't exist independently, isn't that brilliant huh?

Comment: was it a new app when you uploaded apk to production track? does that mean timed publishing works for new app too as long as you have something published in alpha/beta channel?

Comment: Yes I did not have any version of the app in the production track prior to this. Yes timed publishing will work for new app but il will affect ALL tracks- alpha, beta and production at the same time.